# rsync chgrp Failing on NFS

Tags: rsync, nfs, nfs4, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to set up NFS on two servers to share files.  The owner of the files in question have the same UID and GID on NFS Server and each NFS client.

The NFS Server is running on Ubuntu 14.04 and the clients are both 12.04.  The NFS Share is on a ZFS Pool.

I am using NFSv4 with the following /etc/export

```
/mnt/share client1(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,nohide)
/mnt/share client2(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,nohide)
```

When running an rsync from local files to the network share, I get the following error:

```
sudo rsync -av /home/ubuntu/data/ /nfs_test/data/
sending incremental file list
rsync: chgrp "/nfs_test/data/file" failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

Some of the files will complete sucessfully while others will have the same chgrop error. Here is a stat of each file.

On Server:

```
root@nfs_server:~# stat /mnt/share/data/file
  File: ‘/mnt/share/data/file’
  Size: 9095168     Blocks: 17919      IO Block: 131072 regular file
Device: 1ch/28d Inode: 1827        Links: 1
Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: (  150/ tomcat7)   Gid: (  150/ tomcat7)
Access: 2014-07-16 14:11:00.239013999 +0000
Modify: 2013-07-30 10:28:15.000000000 +0000
Change: 2014-07-22 13:44:36.362054644 +0000
 Birth: -
```

On Client:

```
root@client1:/nfs_test# stat /nfs_test/data/file
  File: `/nfs_test/data/file'
  Size: 9095168         Blocks: 17919      IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 16h/22d Inode: 1827        Links: 1
Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: (  150/ tomcat7)   Gid: (  150/ tomcat7)
Access: 2014-07-16 14:11:00.239013999 +0000
Modify: 2013-07-30 10:28:15.000000000 +0000
Change: 2014-07-22 13:44:36.362054644 +0000
 Birth: -
```

I am unsure why this is happening, any advice?

Comment: Please submit the specific rsync command line you are using to do this and on which system.

Comment: I have updated it to show the rsync command being used

Comment: What happens when you avoid NFS and do it over SSH?

Comment: Is there already a file in that directory called "file"?  What if you add a "." to the end of the source and dest?  sudo rsync -av /home/ubuntu/data/. /nfs_test/data/.

Comment: There is already a file in both directories called file, and from the looks of it, it is the same file (so maybe the rsync is working?).  I tried the rsync again with a "." at the end, but same result.